# Data Import Not Geocoding Everyone from Excel File

Tags: carto, geocoding, import, excel

I'm new to this, so please go lightly if I'm asking something obvious.

I imported an Excel file with 9,159 entries and I'm mystified as to why 841 are cartodb_georef_status false and another 36 null.  So, something like a tenth of the data isn't getting mapped.  Many are international addresses which I am less familiar with, but even American addresses like:

`fname lname nickname   1609 Mulberry Lane      Wentachee   WA  98801   USA`

get false and

`fname lname nickname  301 Church Street        Mount Calvary   WI  53057   USA`

gets a null.

These seem like legit addresses to me and both of the above examples return valid results on Google maps.

Comment: You're correct, I didn't phrase that as clearly as I could have.  I'll change the title and hope that a CartoDB person can weigh in.

Answer (score 1):

If the dataset was geocoded automatically by the upload, it was geocoded by your city column but not by the address.

CartoDB, unless disabled in the Connect Dataset section, tries to guess automatically the types of the columns and also tries to get a column for which the dataset could be geocoded by Country name, City name or IP address.

Probably CartoDB found your city column and it run the city names geocoder against it, but the complete address would need a manual geocoding by using the "Street Addresses" option which requires geocoding credits as it is offered via a geocoding provided and not directly by CartoDB as the other options are.

If you want to geocode your dataset by address, you'd need to remove the cartodb_georef_status column and configure the geocoding process with the street addresses option.

The reason why not all the dataset was geocoded is simple: the system didn't detect the names. This could be caused because the system doesn't contain a name at all, or because CartoDB recognizes it with another different name.

CartoDB uses the [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) database in order to geocode city names, so you could try to find the city there and check which nomenclature is the database using. Notice that only the geonames locations specified as "Populated places" (marked with a white icon and the letter P) are in the CartoDB geocoding database.

You could also post the not geocoded cities here to see if there's something we could help you with.

Comment: Here's the list:

Comment: Here's the list of cities that are in

`SELECT distinct(CITY) FROM sasquan_201507_19 WHERE cartodb_georef_status IS false OR cartodb_georef_status IS NULL`

http://pastebin.com/rnzDKFy0

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Weird, I'm seeing there cities that I'm sure are recognised. Which is your username? Perhaps this was due to an error (for example, a quota error)

Comment: Thanks! I'm seeing that geocoding manually the datasets gets more data geocoded, so this seems to be something related with the automatic guessing